# Holding Down Backspace not Triggering Keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, backspace

I'm trying to write text from an input to a div on keyup with javascript and jquery by checking if the current value of the input is the same as the previous value of the input. This works fine except when you hold down the backspace key until all of the text is gone from the input. In this case it doesn't update the variables that I'm using for some reason. This happens in all browsers and only if all of the text is deleted, also only if the backspace key is used (instead of another key)

I'm pretty new at javascript so any tips are appreciated :)

javascript:

```
    fsa = (function() {

        var inputId = "";
        var sigId = "";

        function resetOnFocus() {
            inputId = document.activeElement.id;
            sigId = "sig-" + document.activeElement.id;
        }

        function getText() {
            lastentry = $("#" + inputId).val();
        }

        function writeText() {

            if ($("#" + inputId).val() != lastentry) {
                document.getElementById(sigId).innerHTML = 'current entry :' + $("#" + inputId).val() + '</br>last entry: ' + lastentry;
            }
        }

        return {
            resetOnFocus: resetOnFocus,
            getText: getText,
            writeText: writeText
        }

    })();

    //call the functions

    //clear variables on focus
    $('input').focus(function() {
        fsa.resetOnFocus();
    });

    //get input value on key press
    $('input').keydown(function() {
        fsa.getText();
    });

    //prints input value on keyup if input value is new
    $('input').keyup(function() {
        fsa.writeText();
    });
```

and html:

```
<input id="first-name" class="i1" />
<div id="sig-first-name" class="o1" /></div>
<input id="last-name" class="i2" />
<div id="sig-last-name" class="o2" /></div>
```

Comment: When you press down then how can `keyup` event fired unitl you up key?

Comment: Keydown is used to check whats in the input field before the character is entered. Keyup is used to compare that value with the input's value after the character has been entered. The code above works fine aside from the problem I asked.

Comment: Use `oninput` event instead of key events, it is triggered only when a change has occured.

Comment: How about using the onchange event?

Comment: `onchange` wouldn't detect changes in real-time. [A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ok4jjhnp/1/) shows how to use `oninput`.

Comment: Cheers Teemu, works great!